# Is it true that everything is a side effect in C?

Tags: programming-languages, c

I'm just a beginner, I've started learning programming, CS, math, and Unix. I know how to code in Pascal and also study C.
In the university a professional programmer, who teaches coding, said that literally everything in C is a side effect.

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.(from the internet)

And he says that even printf() has a side effect. E.g.

```
printf('Hello, world\n');
```

returns 13 and also prints "Hello, world", or that there's no "assignment statement" in C, only "assignment operator/operation", so we can do thing like this:

```
x = (y = 1) - 3;
```

which actually causes a side effect.
It's not the same as

```
a := b;
```

in pascal.
Or this:

```
a[foo(x)] += y;
```

is not the same as

```
a[foo(x)] = a[foo(x)] + y;
```

because foo(x) might return different numbers.

It confuses me. I know that side effects are not usually good because it muddles readability of the code and sometimes makes it behave unexpectedly.
Please, clarify what actually happens here.

Comment: Reading a non-volatile value: No side effect. Calling a function without side effects: No side effect. (void) (x + y/3): No side effect.

Comment: x = y+3: changing x is a “side effect”. You’d be rather stuffed without side effects. So “not usually good” is total nonsense.

Comment: `there's no "assignment operator" in C` I beg to differ: [6.5.16 Assignment operators](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf). There is no *assignment statement* I remember *Algol languages* including Pascal to have.

Comment: `clarify what actually happens here` What's actually happen in a correct interpretation/execution of a program in a programming language is part of the specification of that language, of its reference/standard document. What happens between lecturer and student is way more complicated. The problems may start with `those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment` being intended as a *definition*, without you quoting the lecturer to explicitly say so.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, I meant "assignment statement". Because in Russian language literally everyone calls any statement "operator" (and everyone understands what they're talking about). In English it's a different word. So I meant there's no assignment statement like in Pascal, but only operation, or, "operator". Just a little confusion.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following definition, which IMO is relevant:

"A side effect is when a function relies on, or modifies, something outside its parameters to do something. For example, a function which reads or writes from a variable outside its own arguments, a database, a file, or the console can be described as having side effects."

The operations listed fall in this category.

---

As regards the assignment, I would rather say that the C assignment is an *operator*, as it creates an expression with an rvalue (like c= a + b, c= (a = b) has meaning). Pascal's assignment is an *operation*. I would not say that assignment in itself has (or is ?) a side effect.

Comment: That's not the definition that the C Standard or the C++ Standard are using. Since the question is about C, the relevant definition is from 5.1.2.3 of the C Standard: "Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment".

Comment: @gnasher729: the two definitions are perfectly compatible, that's what I meant.

Comment: Yes, I meant "assignment statement". Because in Russian language literally everyone calls any statement "operator" (and everyone understands what they're talking about). In English it's a different word. So I meant there's no assignment statement like in Pascal, but only operation, or, "operator". Just a little confusion. I heard about this translation mistake but just forgot :D
So, there's no assignment in

Comment: @GeorgeGlebov: misplaced comment I guess.